# reference variable in function definition

Tags: javascript

```
element.onmouseover = function onmouseover(event){ this.src=oldLinkImageOver; };
```

the variable `oldLinkImageOver` is a variable holding the string "images/image.png", but `alert(element.onmouseover);` on this will come out as `oldLinkImageOver` rather than what it references.

Is there a way to have `oldLinkImageOver` be the value it references rather than the name of the reference?

Comment: Can't you just use `.element:hover { background-image: url(images/image.png); }`... ? (Of course you would have to replace the IMG element with a SPAN (for instance).)

Comment: err... it should already be the value. Try doing console.log(oldLinkImageOver) inside the event handler to check it out. (I'm suggesting console.log instead of alert because it is much more convenient if you are on a decent browser with a debugger/developer tools)

Comment: @missingno I see your `console.log` and raise you `debugger;`... `:P`

Comment: @user101 - You are asking how to take `myFunction.toString()` and parse the values of its variables?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I'm pretty sure it's not what you seem to want to do.

Why do you want to alert out the `element.onmouseover` function? It will alert the text of that particular function.

If you want to check the value of the `oldLinkImageOver` variable, you can always alert simply that (note that alerting is not the best way of debugging your code, use the browsers built in debugger with breakpoints and other manly things).

If you want to somehow get the text of the function and replace the oldLinkImageOver variable with it's contents you can do it like this:

```
alert(element.onmouseover.toString().replace('oldLinkImageOver','"' + oldLinkImageOver + '"'));
```

Keep that in mind that it's just string replace so if there are other parts of the function containing the text "oldLinkImageOver" it will also get replaced.

EDIT: Sorry for necromancing this, but I just browsed old unanswered questions and thought I should answer some regardless of the chance of ever getting accepted, or even noticed.